# Not passing the variable to another function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to pass the value from one function to another in JavaScript but when I am trying to do this it is not working. 
The problem is with `floaded2()` function to get the value of the `theYoutubeGlobalState`.

**HTML**:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
    <script src = "jquery.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body dir = "rtl">

            <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/-cSFPIwMEq4" onload="floaded2()" title="YouTube video player" id="player" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="400" width="500"></iframe>

    </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
var theYoutubeGlobalState;
        //onYouTubePlayerAPIReady
        function floaded() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                videoId: '-cSFPIwMEq4',
                events: {
                    'onStateChange': function (event) {

                        theYoutubeGlobalState=event.data;                    }
                }
            });
        }

        function floaded2() {
            switch ( theYoutubeGlobalState )
             {
                 case 0:
                   alert("Ended");
                   break;
                 case 1:
                    alert("Playing"); 
                   break;
                 case 2:
                    alert("Paused"); 
                   break;            
            }
        }
```

You can check it: http://jsfiddle.net/3GGHW/1/. Could you please tell me what's the problem.

Comment: This is not very helpful. You don't mention which functions, or which values. Moreover, with Fiddles, please put your JS in the dedicated JS panel rather than lumping it in with the HTML. It is always helpful to post the code as part of your question - we shouldn't *have* to click out just to help.

Comment: As above, it would be helpful if you said which values and which functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work here:

http://jsfiddle.net/3GGHW/2/

You set the wrong function to the onload event handler in the HTML -- needs to be `floaded()` not `floaded2()` -- and you needed to call `floaded2()` from `floaded()`. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to invoke `floaded()` at all. In the future, try pasting a [reduced] test case directly into your question.